# How to make round background selector for round image button?

Tags: android, drawing

I'm trying to make a background selector for round button as a ring around a button. Something like in AOS4.1 for tablettes for buttons Home/Back etc. So to achieve it I'm using the following selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:state_selected="false"/>

    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape 
            android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
            android:useLevel="false" >
            <solid android:color="@color/btn_background" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

It actually works but it draws a solid ring. Actually I want it to be bigger than button itself like a ring around the button. Is there any way to to do it or do I have to write a separate xml with separate sizes for my every single round image button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one thing. In your shape use **`@android:color/transparent`** as `solid` color and use a `stroke` with the desired border color.

```
    <shape 
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke android:color="@color/btn_background" android:width="1dp"/>
    </shape>
```

It will create a cyclic border outside the button. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thanx for the answer! It must be something like that. The only problem is to have right width to make it somehow universal or I would have to create separate xml for every single round image button. If I use one xml then smaller buttons has wider ring (looks like 10px) but bigger ones has thinner ring, which looks like 1-2px or no ring at all. I set android:width="10dp"

Comment: no need to create separate xml. create a custom  button with custom parameters. So you can use single design by using different parameters

Comment: Didn't really get it. Smaller buttons gets bigger visible ring while bigger ones - smaller. Maybe that depends on ImageButton's size like its container or something. On a tablet this behavior looks much more nice.

Comment: actually the stroke size is always 1dp ... so in small buttons it looks like this .. you can try creating from program using ShapeDrawable